# We're sorry but sf doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a Vuejs app that makes an Axios call. I Dockerized it and used digitalocean to serve it to the cloud. App is working but after any axios call, i am getting "We're sorry but sf doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue." as response.
-I have tried changing the port from 8080 to 8081, running the app on incognito browser tab, changing "baseUrl" with "baseURL" and in front-end docker file i was installing libraries with npm, i also tried to use yarn  but i still have this issue.

Is there any more idea about how to fix it ?

[image]

main.js file

```
    createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(vue3GoogleLogin, {
    clientId:
      "******",
  })
  .component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
  .component("MazBtn", MazBtn)
  .component("MazInput", MazInput)
  .component("MazPhoneNumberInput", MazPhoneNumberInput)
  .component("Datepicker", Datepicker)
  // .component("VueGlide", VueGlide)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");
```

Frontend Docker file ;

```
#Base image
FROM node:lts-alpine

#Install serve package
RUN npm i -g serve

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the project files
COPY . .

# Build the project
# Build the project
RUN npm run build

# Expose a port
EXPOSE 3000

# Executables
CMD [ "serve", "-s", "dist" ]
```

Backend docker file

```
FROM python:3.10-bullseye


# Working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the dependencies
COPY ./docs/requirements.txt /app

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the files
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/backend

ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
# Executable commands
CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

vue.config.js file ;

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,

  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    proxy: {
      // "/upload/img": {
      //   // target: "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
      //   target: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
      // },

      "/api": {
        // target: "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
      },
      "/media": {
        target: "http://localhost:8000",
      },
      "/http-bind": {
        target: "https://localhost:8443",
        logLevel: "debug",
      },
    },
    // https: true,
    // watchContentBase: false,
  },
});
```

Comment: I used flask for backend. It is working fine on local. I am not sure where should i have this app.get("*",...).  I didint write anything like that on front end or back end. I can share my main.js file if its gonna help ?

Comment: or maybe its and issue about my docker files ?

Comment: Is the issue related to Vue2 or 3 here? Also, do you run a local dev server here or opening just a file? Do you have some code to share us? Or a [repro]?

Comment: I am using vue3. I am running it on a container with digitalocean. I can share my mainjs, front-back docker files if its needed

Comment: I shared mainjs, and docker files if you would like to see

Answer (score 1):

Your backend requests are being handled by the frontend app. It looks like you are relying on the development server's proxy functionality in order to forward them to the backend, but this will (and should) not be active when you deploy your app. Instead you will need another proxy that sends /api requests to your backend and other requests to your frontend.